# How can i slow down particles after baking

Tags: particles, baking

I have a baked particle simulation that is perfectly fine but way to fast, so I want to slow it down as you would do it in dopesheet in case of a keyframe animation.

I found solutions to bake particles to keyframes with one instancing object, but i got 5 in this case and planing to have even more.
And maybe there is a non python way, i'm not that good at it yet.

I would really like this custom-ability feature because its hard to see the speed of the simulation before baking and baking is slow with many particles and object instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other applications like houdini and maya, softimage (ICE) have a re-time cache function. Such thing doesn´t exist in Blender.
The closest thing that could emulate your effect is if your simulation is CACHED in open VDB and you export the sequence. Then create a second particle emmiter (on a new scene) and retime the flow of the particles first, then from the previously exported open VDB, using LOAD CACHE options your new (retimed) emmitter should work with the previous VDB cached simulation.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information!! Now i realise i didnt mention molecular script. New Problem, it crashes blender on external cache, while trying to your rebuild you solution